# .zshrc not working (accidentally deleted first line)

Tags: zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I deleted the first line from my .zshrc and now nothing I put in .zshrc has any effect, I'm not sure what it was but it was there when I opened .zshrc the very first time.

All that is in my ~/.zshrc is the fallowing:

```
alias 'c=clear' 'cl=clear' 'hist=history' 'h=history' 'll=ls -l' 'v=cat'
```

`PATH=$PATH:.`

```
ZSH_THEME="fino"
```

None of the commands work, is there something else I need in the .zshrc to make it work?

Comment: While deleting that line *may* have caused the problems, the reason why it is not working now lies with what is still there. Without knowing the contents of your `~/.zshrc` it will be impossible to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I found my answer… after too long.

All zsh commands that do not work in bash already need to be in-between

```
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
```

and

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```